# got error 22 from storage engine mysql

Tags: windows, mysql

mysqldump: Error: 'got error 22 from storage engine' when trying to dump
 tablespaces
mysqldump: Got error: 23: Out of resources when opening file '.\database\table.MYD' (Errcode: 24) when using LOCK TABLES

i got this error when trying to make a dump in any database that I select  , looks like that database is corrupted , is possible repair that ?

Comment: Probably not corrupted data. Does a simple `SELECT * FROM the_table` work?

Comment: a select * from table works ... any table of the database ...

Comment: What command are you running?

Answer (score 2):

You seem to have reached the maximum number of open files. This limit is either MySQL's or the system's.

- increase the value for the [`open_files_limit`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_open_files_limit) in your MySQL configuration file (this directive does not exist in a default installation, so you might need to create it in the `[mysqld]` section)
- [increase the limit at system level](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3735000/1446005) (but I am not sure this applies to Windows)

Answer (score 2):

[Here](https://philip.yurchuk.com/software/mysql-failed-to-open-file-error-2-and-22-on-windows/) are some reasons for this error:

> ```
> Type “source path-to-SQL-file“. BUT, you must follow these rules:
> ```
>
> - Use the full source command, not the . shortcut.
> - Have no spaces in your path. I copied mine to a root of a drive. Note    that spaces in the file name is OK, just not the path.
> - Do not quote the file name, even if it has spaces. This gave error 22.
> - Use forward slashes in the path, e.g., C:/path/to/filename.sql.    Otherwise you’ll get error 2.
> - Do not end with a semicolon.

Comment: Thanks for this, it was quotes round the file name that did it for me

Answer (score 1):

Please check your read write access to the drive where you have stored your mySQL database.
error 22 occurred usually when you have no write access to that drive.