# Difference between Linux errno 23 and Linux errno 24

Tags: c, linux, sockets, error-code, errno

1. What is the difference between these 2 linux errors in `errno.h`? 23 and 24

   I tried 2 different sites but can't understand difference between the two.

   ---

   ```
   [EMFILE]
   Too many open files.
   [ENFILE]
   Too many files open in system.
   ```

   ---

   ```
   # define ENFILE      23  /* File table overflow */
   # define EMFILE      24  /* Too many open files */
   ```

   ---
2. Also, I am getting errno 24 and socket call failing at 974th time. (`AF_INET` UDP datagram socket)

   When I did a `cat /proc/sys/fs/file-max` I am seeing a value of 334076
   ulimit -n showing 1024

   Any idea what can be done to increase limit?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

For 1) Both error codes are about the situation with too many opened files. EMFILE is too many files opened in your process. ENFILE is too many files opened in the entire system.

Comment: Thanks wojtek. For EMFILE error, do you know where can i set max limit for files that can be opened by the process?

Comment: I am seeing value of 334076 for /proc/sys/fs/file-max

Comment: Look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3734932/max-open-files-for-working-process

Answer (score 7):

You can increase the maximum number of open files / file descriptors

```
sysctl -w fs.file-max=100000
```

Or open

```
/etc/sysctl.conf
```

and append/change fs.file-max to the number you need:

```
fs.file-max = 100000
```

Then run

```
sysctl -p
```

to reload the new settings

If you don't want to set system-wide FD (file-descriptor) limits, you can set the user-level FD limits.

You need to edit 
`/etc/security/limits.conf file`

And for user YOUR_USER, add these lines:

```
YOUR_USER soft nofile 4096
YOUR_USER hard nofile 10240
```

to set the soft and hard limits for user YOUR_USER.
Save and close the file.

To see the hard and soft limits for user YOUR_USER:

```
su - YOUR_USER

ulimit -Hn
ulimit -Sn
```

Comment: But i am already seeing values of 1024 for Hn and Sn. So should not fail at 974th creation right.

Comment: @badri: Not unless the system has another 50 fds open.

Comment: @badri: Are you sure you didn't forget anywhere to close any stream/socket/connection ?

Comment: Hi Quandary - i need them all in parallel. will be closing them later. but as you said, i will try increasing it to 4096 and see if it helps first.

Comment: changing limits in /etc/security/limits.conf helped. thanks !

Comment: quandary - i was mistaken. sorry. i thought changing limits helped, but cat /proc/3688/limits | grep files
still shows Max open files            1024                 1024                 files
Even sysctl and  sysctl -p
has not helped. Tried setting huge values ulimit -Sn to 4096/8192 but still no effect.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3734932/max-open-files-for-working-process sent by wojtek also suggests that i have to use setrlimit within process. http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/getrlimit.html. Does it mean i have to invoke it from within the process (i.e., C file itself). Surely there should be some linux command to set these limits?