# Ruby: Too many open files @ rb_sysopen

Tags: ruby

After opening a file with `File.new(big_file)` (without closing it) 1016 times (Ubuntu) or 1017 times (CentOS), it seems there is a limit and it raises:

```
Too many open files @ rb_sysopen - big_file (Errno::EMFILE)
```

Is there any way to raise that limit?

On my systems, `ulimit` is set to `unlimited`.

Comment: Check `ulimit -n` not `ulimit`. I'm willing to bet it's `1024`.

Comment: Also, I'd recommend following some of the instructions [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24862733/difference-between-linux-errno-23-and-linux-errno-24) to fix this.

Comment: Normal filesystem limits are 1024 open filehandles, many of those already reserved or used internally by Ruby. `ulimit` settings need to be adjusted here. One way to fix this is to fuss with `/etc/sysctl.conf` and `/etc/security/limits.conf`.

Comment: @EliSadoff `ulimit -n` is indeed `1024`, you won the bet! So how can I raise that?

Comment: Either by running `sysctl -w fs.file-max=NUMBER_OF_FILES` or edit `/etc/sysctl.conf` and change the value of `fs.file-max` and then run `sysctl -p` to reload the file settings. Read [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24862823/5021321) for more details.

Comment: @EliSadoff didn't work, see my edit.

Comment: @Victor Did you try the second part of the answer, setting it just for your user instead of system wide? That seems to work better.

Comment: @EliSadoff It did! Thank you. I'll edit this question and make another Q/A one to separate the two different issues: The fact `Errno::EMFILE` means per process and the issue with `file-max=` not working.

Comment: @Victor how to do the same with windows ? I am having the same problem. Can you please help me out ?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

- `EMFILE` is too many files opened in your process.
- `ENFILE` is too many files opened in the entire system.

So `Errno::EMFILE` is due to the ruby process opening too many files. This limit is probably set to the default `1024` can be seen with:

```
$ulimit -n
1024
```

Instead of:

```
$ulimit
unlimited
```

You can raise the limit using [this method](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40617652/1455070).

Comment: I am having the same problem but my system is windows. So how I can set limit for windows .

Comment: For macOS you can raise the limit by running `ulimit -n 8192`

Comment: @huwr any reason you picked 8192?

Comment: @kraftydevil no reason. I just liked the number.

Comment: My `ulimit -n` was `256` (macOS Mojave, Mac Mini 2012). I changed it with `ulimit -n 1024` and the problem was gone.