# Cannot change the maximum open files per process with sysctl

Tags: linux, centos6, ubuntu-16.04

My actual limit is `1024`:

```
$ ulimit -a
core file size          (blocks, -c) 0
data seg size           (kbytes, -d) unlimited
scheduling priority             (-e) 0
file size               (blocks, -f) unlimited
pending signals                 (-i) 95979
max locked memory       (kbytes, -l) 64
max memory size         (kbytes, -m) unlimited
open files                      (-n) 1024
pipe size            (512 bytes, -p) 8
POSIX message queues     (bytes, -q) 819200
real-time priority              (-r) 0
stack size              (kbytes, -s) 10240
cpu time               (seconds, -t) unlimited
max user processes              (-u) 1024
virtual memory          (kbytes, -v) unlimited
file locks                      (-x) unlimited
```

I tried:

```
sysctl -w fs.file-max=100000
```

and appending to `/etc/sysctl.conf`:

```
fs.file-max = 100000
```

without success, even after running `sysctl -p` to reload the settings and/or rebooting, on both Ubuntu 16.04 and CentOS 6.

It always stays set to `1024`.

---

*This question is an extension of that [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40597488/ruby-too-many-open-files-rb-sysopen).*

Comment: `fs.file-max` is not the tunable for per-process open file descriptor limits... It controls the maximum number of file handles the kernel will allocate, which must be able to handle all open files for all currently running processes.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

For Ubuntu 17.04. See [this solution](https://superuser.com/a/1200818/385027).

Prior to Ubuntu 17.04:

I don't know why the above settings don't work but it seems you can get the same result by using the [`/etc/security/limits.conf` file](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/en/man5/limits.conf.5.html).

#### Set the limit in `/etc/security/limits.conf`

```
sudo bash -c "echo '* - nofile 10240' >> /etc/security/limits.conf"
```

- `*` means all users. You can replace it by a specific username.
- `-` means both `soft` and `hard` for the [type of limit to be enforced](https://serverfault.com/questions/265155/soft-limit-vs-hard-limit). Hard can only be modified by the superuser. Soft can be modified by a non-root user and cannot be superior to hard.
- `nofile` is the *Maximum number of open files* parameter.
- `10240` is the new limit.

#### Reload

Logout and log back in. `sudo sysctl -p` doesn't seem to be enough to reload.

You can check the new limit with:

```
ulimit -n
```

---

*Tested on Ubuntu 16.04 and CentOS 6. Inspired by this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24862733/difference-between-linux-errno-23-and-linux-errno-24/24862823#24862823).*

Comment: For macOS you can raise the limit by running `ulimit -n 8192`

Comment: `ulimit -n 8192` seems to also work on Ubuntu 18 as well, while also avoiding having to restart or log out/in

Answer (score 12):

For MacOs 10.14.6 and above, the below works if you need to up the limit temporarily:

Check your current limit:

```
ulimit -n
```

Mine was 256

Change it:

```
ulimit -n 1024
```

Check it again in the same tab:

```
ulimit -n
```

Mine now shows 1024.

The change is immediate, no need to log out and in again, or open a new Terminal tab. That fixed my particular problem.

Unfortunately, the change is temporary. Later, when you open a new Terminal window, you'll be back with your old value and problem.