# Socket creation failing during choose_kex in openssh package

Tags: networking, ssh, openssh

I am trying to edit openssh package & add custom code to create socket and send some message.
in other part of openssh package i am able to do but not able to perform same task in openssh-7.8p1->kex.c->choose_kex & in packet.c where we return error from

Code :

```
{
int sock = 0;
sock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
if(sock < 0) {
   debug("%s: Unable to create socket: %s",__func__, strerror(errno));
   return;
}
close(sock);
}
```

above code return error with log : too many open files (error code:24)

is it not possible to create socket while ssh handshake in progress?

Comment: I`ve already  tried increasing max open file descriptors it didn`t help

Comment: Is it in the server or the client? Can you tell me what you really want to do?

Comment: You're trying to open a socket and getting error 24 which has [a particular meaning](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24862733/13317). What kind of answer are you looking for here?

Comment: this is server. i am creating a patch to send msg when negotiation of keyExchange algorithm between C & S fails during ssh handshake. 

At this time current open file descriptors are under limit & not exceeding. even to be safe side i`ve tried setting max open file descriptor limit to hard high value. still same error persists. 

if i do socket open in later part of code , i am able to but not during keyExchange in openssh. 

i am looking for answer why socket creation or any normal file creation can fail during keyExchange in openssh code & how do i solve that?