# Database to manage million log files

Tags: database, logging, frameworks

I wish to have large number (e.g. million) of log files on a system. But OS has limit on opened files. It is not efficient to create million files in single folder.

**Is there ready solution, framework or database that will create log files and append data to log files in efficient manner?**

I can imagine various techniques to optimize management of large number of log files but there might something that does that out of box.

e.g. I wish that log file was re-created every day or when it reach 50MB. Old log files must be stored. e.g uploaded to Amazon S3.

I can imagine that `log database` writes all logs in single file but later processes it appends records in millions of files.

May be there is special file system that is good for such task. I can't find anything. I am sure there might be solution.

**PS** I wish to run logging on single server. I say 1 million because it is more then default limit on opened files. 1 million files 1MB is 1TB and it could be stored on regular harddrive.

I look for existing solution before I will write my own. I am sure there might a set of logging servers. I just do not know how to search for them.

Comment: Why not just use some standard logging framework like log4J and create a simple scheduled task that will be moving log files once per day or when file will be larger than ... KB?

Comment: e.g. I have 1 million of users and 10.000 will be logged today. I wish to have 1 log file per user. I do not wish to re-invent the wheel if there is some solution to manager many log files. There might cache of opened files, routines to flush opened files every X seconds.

Comment: to be honest I believe that having a log file for each user seems to be a result of really bad design - you should really think about another approach imo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would start thinking of a Cassandra of Hadoop as a store for log data and eventually if you want these data in a form of a files write a procedure that will make a select on one of these databases and place them in formatted files.

Comment: The problem with regular database is that they are designed to index data. It is not efficient to write logs in regular database.

Comment: Cassandra is designed for clusters. I am looking for solution to run on a single system with single drive.

Comment: From what I see if you set up a single node HDFS server then you have configuration parameter dfs.namenode.fs-limits.max-directory-items to 0 and have no limit for number of files in single directory. (Limit by memory avaialble only). An then just use this in you app.

Comment: The question is if you really need to have open at the same time 10k of files or more ? I see on linux the default limit per process is 64k using the ulimit -n command to get this information.

Comment: Some interesting information on how to change per process open files limit for linux server is here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3734932/max-open-files-for-working-process