# Epoll tcp server grinds to a halt when accepting connections

Tags: c, linux, sockets, networking, epoll

I'm trying to connect 10,000+ tcp clients to my tcp server below. After 1-5 seconds I'm able to get between 200 and 5000 clients connected before the code grinds to a halt and hangs without terminating. I cant find any further documentation on this and the gprof profiler isnt able to collect any data.

Server:

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <assert.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <sys/epoll.h>
#include <netdb.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <iostream>

#ifndef MAXEVENTS
#define MAXEVENTS 64
#endif
#ifndef TX_BUF_SIZE
#define TX_BUF_SIZE (65535)
#endif
#ifndef RX_BUF_SIZE
#define RX_BUF_SIZE (65535)
#endif

char buf[RX_BUF_SIZE];

void user_recv_handler(int efd, int fd, char * buf, int len)
{
    int s = -1;
    struct epoll_event ev;
    ev.data.fd = fd;
    ev.events = EPOLLOUT | EPOLLET;
    s = epoll_ctl(efd, EPOLL_CTL_MOD, fd, &ev);
    //assert(s!=-1);
    if(s==-1)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "epoll out error.\n");
        return;
    }
}

struct addrinfo* tcpipv4_getaddrinfo(char* port)
{
    struct addrinfo hints;
    struct addrinfo *res;
    int s;

    bzero(&hints, sizeof(struct addrinfo));
    hints.ai_family = AF_INET; // ipv4 addrs 
    hints.ai_socktype = SOCK_STREAM; // TCP
    hints.ai_flags = AI_PASSIVE;
    s = getaddrinfo(NULL, port, &hints, &res);
    //assert(s==0);
    if (s)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "failed to getaddrinfo: %s\n", gai_strerror(s));
        return NULL;
    }
    return res;
}


struct addrinfo* tcpipv6_getaddrinfo(char* port)
{
    struct addrinfo hints;
    struct addrinfo *res;
    int s;

    bzero(&hints, sizeof(struct addrinfo));
    hints.ai_family = AF_INET6; // ipv4 addrs 
    hints.ai_socktype = SOCK_STREAM; // TCP
    hints.ai_flags = AI_PASSIVE;
    s = getaddrinfo(NULL, port, &hints, &res);
    //assert(s==0);
    if (s)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "failed to getaddrinfo-ipv6: %s\n", gai_strerror(s));
        return NULL;
    }
    return res;
}

int set_nonblock(int fd)
{
    int flags = -1;
    if(-1 == (flags = fcntl(fd, F_GETFL, 0)))
    {
        return -1;
    }
    flags |= O_NONBLOCK;
    if( fcntl(fd, F_SETFL, flags) == -1 )
    {
        return -1;
    }
    return 0;
}

int tcpipv4_createfd_bind(struct addrinfo* rp)
{
    int flags = -1;
    int s;
    // create socket 
    int sfd = socket(rp->ai_family, rp->ai_socktype, rp->ai_protocol);
    //assert(sfd!=-1);
    if (sfd == -1) 
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "failed to create socket\n");
        return -1;
    }
    // bind
    s = bind(sfd, rp->ai_addr, rp->ai_addrlen);
    //assert(s==0);
    if(s!=0)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "failed to bind socket %d\n", sfd);
        return -1;
    }
    // nonblock
    s = set_nonblock(sfd);
    //assert(s != -1);
    if (s == -1)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "failed to set nonblocking socket %d\n", sfd);
        return -1;
    }
    return sfd;
}

int writen(int fd, char * buf, size_t len)
{
    char * cur = buf;
    int n = -1;
    while(len>0)
    {
        n = write(fd, cur, len);
        if (n<=0)
        {
            if(errno == EINTR) continue;
            else return -1;
        }
        len -= n;
        cur += n;
    }
    return 0;
}

int readn(int fd, char* buf, size_t len)
{
    char *cur = buf;
    int n = -1;
    while (len>0)
    {
        n = read(fd, cur, len);
        if (n == -1)
        {
            if (errno == EINTR)
                continue;
            else break;
        }
        else if (n == 0)
            break;
        cur += n; len -= n;
    }
    return (int)(cur-buf);
}

void accept_handler(int efd, int listenfd)
{
    struct epoll_event event;
    int s;
    while(1)
    {
        struct sockaddr in_addr;
        socklen_t in_addrlen = sizeof(struct sockaddr);
        int infd = -1;
        char hbuf[NI_MAXHOST], sbuf[NI_MAXSERV];

        infd = accept(listenfd, &in_addr, &in_addrlen);
        //assert(infd != -1);
        if(infd == -1)
        {
            if(errno == EAGAIN || errno == EWOULDBLOCK)
                ;
            else
                perror("failed to accept\n");
            return;
        }
        s = getnameinfo(&in_addr, in_addrlen, 
                hbuf, sizeof(hbuf), 
                sbuf, sizeof(sbuf),
                NI_NUMERICHOST | NI_NUMERICSERV);
        //assert(s == 0);
        if(s == 0)
        {
            printf("Accept fd %d host %s port %s\n", infd, hbuf, sbuf);
            s = set_nonblock(infd);
            //assert(s!=-1);
            event.data.fd = infd;
            event.events = EPOLLIN | EPOLLET;
            s = epoll_ctl(efd, EPOLL_CTL_ADD, infd, &event);
            //assert(s != -1);
            return;
        }
    }
    return;
}

void read_handler(int efd, int fd)
{
    //do sonething with buf.
    int s = -1;
    s=readn(fd, buf, sizeof(buf));
    buf[s] = 0;
    //printf("recv %d bytes: %s", s, buf);
    if(s < 0)
    {
        close(fd);
        if(-1 == epoll_ctl(efd, EPOLL_CTL_DEL, fd, NULL) )
            fprintf(stderr, "failed to del event of %d\n", fd);
        printf("close conection on fd %d", fd);
    }
    else if(s > 0)
    {
        //std::cout << buf << std::endl;
        //do sonething with buf.
        user_recv_handler(efd, fd, buf, s);
    }
}


void write_handler(int efd, int fd)
{
    writen(fd, buf, strlen(buf));
    if(-1 == epoll_ctl(efd, EPOLL_CTL_DEL, fd, NULL) )
        fprintf(stderr, "failed to del event of %d\n", fd);
//  close(fd);
}

int main(int argc, char ** argv)
{
    char* port = NULL;
    int listenfd = -1;
    struct addrinfo* hostaddr=NULL; 
    struct addrinfo* rp = NULL;
    struct epoll_event event;
    struct epoll_event * events, *cur_ev;
    int efd = -1;
    int num_ev = -1;
    int s;

    port = argv[1];
    // get server ipv4 address by getaddrinfo
    (rp = hostaddr = tcpipv4_getaddrinfo(port));
    // create and bind listening socket
    for(; rp; rp = rp->ai_next)
    {
        (listenfd = tcpipv4_createfd_bind(rp));
        if(-1 == listenfd)
            continue;
    }
    freeaddrinfo(hostaddr); 
    //assert(listenfd!=-1);
    if(listenfd==-1)
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    //start listening 
    (s = listen(listenfd, SOMAXCONN));
    //assert(s!=-1);
    if(s == -1)
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    // create epoll
    efd = epoll_create(MAXEVENTS);
    //assert(efd != -1);
    if(efd == -1)
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);

    event.data.fd = listenfd;
    // epoll: read, ET
    event.events = EPOLLIN | EPOLLET;
    s = epoll_ctl(efd, EPOLL_CTL_ADD, listenfd, &event);
    //assert(s!=-1);
    if(s==-1)
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);

    events = (struct epoll_event*)calloc(MAXEVENTS, sizeof(struct epoll_event));

    // event loop;
    while (1)
    {
        num_ev = epoll_wait(efd, events, MAXEVENTS, -1);
        // for each active event: 
        while(num_ev--)
        {
            cur_ev = events+num_ev;
            // close the fd if error (ERR) or hang up (HUP)
            if(cur_ev->events & EPOLLERR || 
                cur_ev->events & EPOLLHUP)
            {
                fprintf(stderr, "epoll get event error\n");
                close(cur_ev->data.fd);
                continue;
            }
            // one or more new connections (fd = listenfd)
            else if(cur_ev->data.fd == listenfd)
            {
                accept_handler(efd, listenfd);
                continue;
            }
            else if(cur_ev->events & EPOLLIN)
            {
                // since the registered event is EPOLLIN, 
                // here we have data on fd waiting for reading.     
                read_handler(efd, cur_ev->data.fd);
            }
            else if (cur_ev->events & EPOLLOUT)
            {
                write_handler(efd, cur_ev->data.fd);
            }
        }
    }
    free(events); events = NULL;
    close(listenfd);
    exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

Client:

```
int connected_count=0;
int i=0;
struct timespec tstart={0,0}, tend={0,0};
clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, &tstart);
for(; i!=10000; i++)
{
    int sockfd;
    int portno = 4000;
    ssize_t n;
    struct sockaddr_in serveraddr;
    struct hostent* server;
    char hostname[] = "127.0.0.1";
    sockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    if(sockfd < 0)
    {
        printf("ERROR opening socket");
        printf("error %d",errno);
        test_function_killall(NULL);
        return;
    }
    server = gethostbyname(hostname);
    if(server == NULL)
    {
        fprintf(stderr,"ERROR, no such host as %s\n", hostname);
        test_function_killall(NULL);
        return;
    }
    bzero((char*)&serveraddr, sizeof(serveraddr));
    serveraddr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    bcopy((char*)server->h_addr, (char*)&serveraddr.sin_addr.s_addr, server->h_length);
    serveraddr.sin_port = htons(portno);
    if(connect(sockfd, (struct sockaddr*)&serveraddr, sizeof(serveraddr)) < 0) 
    {
        printf("ERROR connecting");
        test_function_killall(NULL);
        return;
    }
    else
    {
        std::cout << "active connections " << connected_count++ << std::endl;
    }
    set_nonblock(sockfd);
}   
if(connected_count==10000)
{       
    printf("complete");
}
```

Comment: regarding: `#include <iostream>`  in the server.  This is a C++ header file.  Why is it being included in a C file?

Comment: When compiling. always enable the warnings then fix those warnings.   for `gcc`, at a minimum use: `-Wall -Wextra -Werror -Wconversion -pedantic -std-gnu11`

Comment: Where is your code "grinded to a halt" at.  Is it blocked on "accept" or spinning in a loop.  That will be very valuable information for debuggin

Comment: never access beyond `argv[0]` without first checking `argc` to assure the command line parameter(s) actually exist

Comment: why are statements like: `(listenfd = tcpipv4_createfd_bind(rp));` enclosed in parens?

Comment: regarding statements like: `fprintf(stderr, "failed to bind socket %d\n", sfd);`  it would be much better to call `perror()` so the reason the system thinks the function failed would also be output to `stderr`

Comment: regarding: `Vevents = (struct epoll_event*)calloc(MAXEVENTS, sizeof(struct epoll_event));`  1) when calling any of the heap allocation functions, always check (!=NULL) the returned value to assure the operation was successful.  2) in C, the returned type is `void*` which can be assigned to any pointer.  Casting just clutters the code, making it more difficult to understand, debug, etc

Comment: one of the major problems with the posted code is everything is being handled serially.  The posted code could handle MANY more events if each connection event is passed to a thread (preferably in a thread pool), so the main program can continue to handle the connection (accept()) events.

Comment: The posted code fails to release the client when a call to `read()` returns 0 (I.E. the client has hung up)

Comment: @user3629249 - the value of epoll is that you can multiple a lot of connections on a single thread. (Higher performance than select/poll calls).  But you are correct, more threads would enable higher scalability. But I think the OP needs to get his single-threaded version debugged first before adding more threads.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Start with this:

- Remove the `EPOLLET` flags from the listen socket registration.  You
  might want to remove it from the client connection sockets too.
- Set your listen socket to non-blocking similar to how the client
  connection sockets returned from `accept` are set.

There's all kinds of edge cases with the listen sockets.  I'm not sure, but it appears you aren't fully draining the accept queue when epoll_ctl comes back to indicate that the listen socket has a connection ready. (Think: multiple incoming connections on one edge trigger). It's possible you are blocking on accept and/or stuck on epoll_wait.

**Update:**

- Another thing you could be hitting are the system limits for the maximum number of files handles per process.  Read up [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3734932/max-open-files-for-working-process).

Comment: I had already increased the system file ulimits to 65536 - but good looking out

Comment: changing the listen socket to Level triggered solved the problem. what are the implications of this for a listener socket? will it keep my event loop spinning since its always being notified?

Comment: And what are the implications to setting the listen socket to nonblocking? that didnt have any impact in this exercise.

Comment: By the way, connections seem to be accepted in batches of 200, usually per second. Is this normal?

Comment: ...and after around 10k clients, things speed up and the batching stops.  I see the same behaviour when testing with a different server. Leading me to think this is system related

Comment: @localhost - Changing the listen socket to level triggered is perfectly fine.  epoll_wait will return whenever there's a incoming connection.  Edge Triggering is very difficult to get right - you have to make sure that you drain the queue. Honestly, I don't think you get much of a performance benefit of edge-triggering unless you are trying to do something clever.

Comment: You are welcome to look at my source for an EPOLL based STUN server and the polling abstraction for poll/epoll.  It's a simple protocol. I originally had it as Edge Triggered. But then I extended it to allow for multiple sessions on the same connection, it got too bothersome to keep with ET.  source [here](https://github.com/jselbie/stunserver/blob/master/server/tcpserver.cpp) and [here](https://github.com/jselbie/stunserver/blob/master/networkutils/polling.cpp)